# Запрет на вывод перечисленых файлов

Tags: .htaccess

Из папки выводятся название файлов списком. В этом списке необходимо запретить вывод определенных файлов например: `aaa.php`, `bbb.php`, `ccc.php`.

В папку помещал файл `.htaccess`

```
IndexIgnore  aaa.php, bbb.php, ccc.php
```

Не сработал. 
Почему? Как правильно сделать?

> For example:

```
IndexIgnore *.gif *.jpg *.png accounts.doc
```

> The above code would stop all gif, jpg and png graphics files from being listed.
>   The accounts.doc document would be blocked too however all other .doc files would be shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильно так:

```
IndexIgnore aaa.php bbb.php ccc.php
```

Т.е. имена файлов нужно разделять пробелом.

Если хотите запретить вывод всех файлов с расширением `php`, то правило должно выглядеть так:

```
IndexIgnore *.php
```

Можно и посложнее:

```
IndexIgnore *.htm* *.php
```

Это правило запретит отображение файлов с любым именем и расширением, *начинающимся с `htm`*, а также все файлы с расширением `php`. Но при этом оно пропустит `что_то_там.php5`.

В общем, работают стандартные файловые маски, но альтернативы в директиве `IndexIgnore` должны быть разделены пробелами.

Comment: Такой нюанс: скрипт выводит название файлов php, обрезая  .php (Т.е. aaa bbb ccc списком). Как быть с запретом в этом случае?

Comment: @Serg888 А никак. На скрипт действие `.htaccess` не распространяется. Он действует только на выдачу списка файлов самим Apache (точнее, модулем `mod_autoindex`). Фильтруйте внутри скрипта.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!  Подскажи, как в этой строке `if( substr($name[$i],0,1) != "_") {`   в добавок к файлам с символом _ не выводили еще и файлы с 1-м символом 1(единица)?  Так не работает: != "_" || "1"

Comment: @Serg888 `if (substr($name[$i],0,1) != "_" || if (substr($name[$i],0,1) != "1")`.